# Developing a Firefox/Chrome extension that overlays shapes onto webpages

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I want to create a Firefox add-on or Chrome extension that uses shapes and arrows to teach users how to use websites. After hours of researching, I can't find anyone who has successful overlayed shapes onto webpages. How would I go about doing this?

This question is vague, but I don't know how to clarify. Please ask questions.

Comment: Chrome extensions allow you to manipulate pages with HTML, JS, CSS and other web languages. With CSS you could draw shapes and smoothly show/hide them with jQuery. This question seems like you have done no research. Look into showing/hiding a div with jQuery, that should set you in the right direction. Once you can do that with a normal page, putting it into a Chrome extension should be child's play. Good luck!

Comment: See grumble bubble lib. I use it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this easily. I made a demo for you in a few minutes. I copied a template of mine and changed up some javascript so it adds an arrow image and does an animation when you go to www.bing.com.

Check it out here on github: [GitHub :: Overlay Shapes](https://github.com/Noitidart/Overlay-Shapes)

For demo, download the xpi, after installed into firefox, then go to bing.com and watch the arrow fade in, bounce, than fade out after 5 animation iterations.

You can open up bootstrap.js and edit in `addDiv` function to customize. You don't have to touch anything else, the rest is template cookie cutter stuff.

This is bootstrap add-on. You may want to look into add-sdk, the template/cookie-cutter stuff invisible so the code is like 10 lines, but i dont know sdk.